# Git on windows share remote hung up

Tags: windows, git, share

Two computers. On one its working fine. On the other one I get this

```
Cloning into 'local'...
fatal: unable to get current working directory: No such file or directory
fatal: The remote end hung up upon initial contact
```

when I do

```
git clone file://z:/Git/origin local
```

and

```
fatal: unable to get current working directory: No such file or directory
```

when I do

```
git init --bare x
```

I found several similar issues without any solution like this:
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/26949309-pushing-to-unc-paths-seems-broken-but-mounted-network-drives-works

Is there any way to make git more verbose to find out where the problem is?
How do I solve this problem? I don't know where to start.